# Choosing a Domain for SEO

Tags: seo, domains

I am building a new website and I have a couple domains to choose from. For SEO what are tips for choosing a good domain?

For instance which, in SEO terms, would be better:

`websitesfor[subject-of-website].com` or `[subject-of-websites]-websites.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as SEO for Google, domains that match keywords, otherwise known as Exact Match Domains (EMD) are no longer of benefit. See [this](http://searchengineland.com/google-emd-update-research-and-thoughts-137340) for more on that.

Therefore, you should pick what's best for building building a brand for your website and business that customers and the public will come to recognize.

It would seem `[subject-of-websites]-websites.com` might be more identifiable since the word "websites" is so common that it might not be as easily recognized if placed first. If possible, try to chose a domain without a hyphen, and as few characters as possible, to aid in typing and remembering it

Comment: Create your brand and promote it. It's how merchandizing has always worked. Keep it concise and memorable and establish what it does. `largest-auction-site-on-the-internet-with-store-fronts.com` or `e-bay.com`. One's keyword rich and easily forgotten, the other, well, the rest is history.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Good advice...though `e-bay.com` redirects to `ebay.com` (without the hyphen) ;-)

Comment: Yep, dumb typo. Too many hyphens in the first sample bled into the next one. Which also brings up another issue besides choosing your branding. Always buy the customer misspell domains and direct them to your live site. Otherwise somebody always finds a way to monetize the fat-finger domain, sometimes with embarrassing results to your brand.